# Problems with jmx monitoring in zabbix

Tags: java, jmx, zabbix

I am trying to monitor with JMX using zabbix, but have error :

> unsupported data object type along the path: class
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap

Does some one have ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide more details: what/who provides this error, more details/settings about your Zabbix JMX setup, java/OS/Zabbix versions, do you run JMX Gateway in debug mode?, .......

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to fix this, because Zabbix Java gateway does not support all object types. A similar issue, which asks for ArrayList and LinkedList support, is handled in [ZBXNEXT-1570](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1570). You might wish to leave a comment there.